# Ansible join list items into string including the quotation marks

Tags: list, join, ansible, jinja2

this is probably easy but i cant figure it out

I have a simple list which i need to convert to string but i need each item in the final string to contain quotation marks

```
vars:
  servers:
    - ServerA
    - ServerB
    - ServerC

tasks:
  - name: Join into string
    debug:
      msg: "{{ servers | join(,) }}"

result looks like this
   "msg": "ServerA,ServerB,ServerC"
```

but i need to get the format

```
msg: '"ServerA","ServerB","ServerC"'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Join the items

```yaml
  result: >-
    "{{ servers|join('","') }}"
```

The debug

```yaml
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ result }}"
```

gives the expected result

```yaml
 msg: '"ServerA","ServerB","ServerC"'
```

You can write it into a file

```yaml
  - copy:
      dest: /tmp/result.txt
      content: >
        "{{ servers|join('","') }}"
```

gives

```bash
shell> cat /tmp/result.txt 
"ServerA","ServerB","ServerC"
```

---

Example of a complete playbook for testing

```yaml
- hosts: localhost

  vars:

    servers:
      - ServerA
      - ServerB
      - ServerC

    result: >-
      "{{ servers|join('","') }}"

  tasks:

    - debug:
        msg: "{{ result }}"
    - copy:
        dest: /tmp/result.txt
        content: >
          "{{ servers|join('","') }}"
```

Comment: Thats Nice Vladimir, I was totally confused how the outer parts were getting the doubleqoute but I realise now. Nice work

Answer (score 1):

You can use `regex_replace` inside `map` to iterate over each item in the list and add a double qoute to the start and end of each

```yaml
---
- hosts: localhost
  vars:
    servers:
      - ServerA
      - ServerB
      - ServerC

  tasks:
    - name: Join into string
      debug:
        msg: "{{ servers | map('regex_replace', '^(.*)$', '\"\\1\"') | join(',') }}"
      register: joined_string
    - copy:
        dest: /tmp/test.txt
        content: "{{ servers | map('regex_replace', '^(.*)$', '\"\\1\"') | join(',') }}\n"
```

**OUTPUT**

```
ansible@4acb7f477c6b:/local$ ansible-playbook test.yml
[WARNING]: No inventory was parsed, only implicit localhost is available
[WARNING]: provided hosts list is empty, only localhost is available. Note that the implicit localhost does not match 'all'

PLAY [localhost] **********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] ****************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
Monday 10 April 2023  11:48:06 +0100 (0:00:00.021)       0:00:00.021 **********
ok: [localhost]

TASK [Join into string] ***************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
Monday 10 April 2023  11:48:07 +0100 (0:00:00.706)       0:00:00.728 **********
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "\"ServerA\",\"ServerB\",\"ServerC\""
}

TASK [copy] ***************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
Monday 10 April 2023  11:48:07 +0100 (0:00:00.032)       0:00:00.760 **********
ok: [localhost]

PLAY RECAP ****************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=3    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0

Monday 10 April 2023  11:48:07 +0100 (0:00:00.483)       0:00:01.244 **********
===============================================================================
gather_facts ------------------------------------------------------------ 0.71s
copy -------------------------------------------------------------------- 0.48s
debug ------------------------------------------------------------------- 0.03s
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
total ------------------------------------------------------------------- 1.22s

ansible@4acb7f477c6b:/local$ cat /tmp/test.txt
"ServerA","ServerB","ServerC"
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use a `for` loop, though I admit the already given solutions are nicer.
But here is the play anyways:

```yaml
- name: Test
  hosts: localhost
  vars:
    servers:
      - ServerA
      - ServerB
      - ServerC
    servers_joined: "{% for srv in servers %}'{{ srv }}'{% if not loop.last %},{% endif %}{% endfor %}"

  tasks:
    - name: Join into string
      debug:
        msg:
          - "{{ servers | join(',') }}"
          - '{% for srv in servers %}"{{ srv }}"{% if not loop.last %}, {% endif %}{% endfor %}'
          - "{{ servers_joined }}"
```